# Process of arithmetic operation on 8 bit numbers in C

Tags: c, integer-arithmetic

When we perform arithmetic operation on 8 bit numbers, they are promoted to integers.
I have below code snippet.

```
unsigned char startTime=7;
unsigned char endTime=5;  
unsigned char diff = endTime-startTime;
```

I understand that, in RHS, both are promoted to integers and hence the result is -2 and final result is 254.
I want to know how exactly compiler does this.
This is what I felt, but not sure.
Compiler promotes both of them to integers.
Temporary integer variable is created for the result.
Arithmetic operation is performed.
Result of 5-7 = 0xFFFF FFFF FFFF FFFE . 
Now assign only 8 bits 0xFE to LHS and all higher 3 bytes are stripped off. Hence we see 254 if we print it.

Comment: What is the question? Whether your explanation is true? You can see what the compiler does by looking at the generated assembly.

Comment: all integer operations are performed on the same ALU component of CPU so I guess operations on any data type of size equal to or smaller than word size of the system will involve the operation on the whole word

Comment: What would you expect the final results to be if the unsigned bytes are not promoted to integers?

Comment: I am not saying anywhere that unsigned byte is not promoted. In fact, I am saying it very clearly that they are getting promoted. I just wanted to confirm if it works the same way whatever I wrote. I wrote the way I thought it is going to work, but I wanted a confirmation if it is correct or not.

Comment: @Rajesh: You should always include a question in your question, such as “Is this description of how conversion from `int` to `unsigned char` works correct?”

Comment: Sorry but you can't just "see" from the result and conclude that they are getting promoted to integer without exactly seeing what operations compiler perform. Math can be performed on two unsigned 8-bit numbers and result will be 254.

Comment: @unlut: If I am not mistaken, C promotes chars and shorts to int, before performing arithmetic operations (if there are no other higher ranked operands such as double, float, long etc)

Comment: I am sorry then, I misunderstood your initial post and thought that you were just guessing based on result =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note, `startTime` and `endTime` are promoted to `int`, and the result of `endTime-startTime` is −2. The C standard describes this behavior in terms of the **value** that results, which is −2. It does not describe the behavior in terms of the **bits** that encode the result; it does not mandate that the result be represented by the bits 11111111111111111111111111111110.

In many C implementations, essentially all common modern implementations, the two’s complement system is used for signed integer, in which the 32-bit representation for −2 is 11111111111111111111111111111110. But the C standard also allows using one’s complement (in which −2 is 11111111111111111111111111111101) or sign-and-magnitude (in which −2 is 10000000000000000000000000000010).

Regardless of which system is used, the result of converting −2 to an eight-bit `unsigned char` is 254. (C allows `unsigned char` to be wider than eight bits, but this answer does not address that.) This is because the C standard specifies that the result of converting an integer value to `unsigned char` is the value in the domain of the `unsigned char` type that is obtained by adding or subtracting `UCHAR_MAX+1` repeatedly. That is, it is the value being converted modulo 256. For −2, we have −2 + 256 = 254, so the result required by the C standard is 254.

Since this result is required by the C standard requires of whether two’s complement, one’s complement, or sign-and-magnitude is used, the C compiler (or entire C implementation) is responsible for doing whatever is necessary to get this result. When two’s complement is used, all the compiler has to do is take the low eight bits of the `int` representation and use them as the bits of the `unsigned char` representation. This is one of the reasons two’s complement is favored today. If the C implementation were using one’s complement or sign-and-magnitude, it would be responsible for doing whatever work is necessary to convert the −2 `int` value into a 254 `unsigned char` value.